# How to get specific HTML items into an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, android, html, arraylist

I'm trying to understand how to make use of the HTML data from the APOD archive. Preferably my end goal is to end up with an ArrayList of Strings like so:

From this url `view-source:http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html`

get each of these `2015 February 26:  <a href="ap150226.html">Love and War by Moonlight</a><br>`

and put them into an `ArrayList`

---

I'm more used to JSON or even XML from rest API's -- parsing through HTML just seems crazy hard, so it'd be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on these HTML Parser called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download).
This will make your task easy.

This [link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) would be helpfull for extracting the values from html.

For example:-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html").get();
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("b");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Parse as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using JAXP because you know what element it is that contains the data you want. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/